# Help with proof about functions and subsets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Problem:** let $f: A \rightarrow B$. Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if for all $D \subset A$ we have that $f^{-1}(f(D)) = D$.

**Proof:** 
=> Suppose $f$ is injective. Let $x \in f^{-1}(f(D))$. Then we have that $f(x) \in f(D)$. This means that there is an $y \in D$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. Since $D \subset A$, we have $y \in A$. Since $x = y$ (because of injectivity), we have $x \in D$. Hence $f^{-1}(f(D)) \subset D$.

Now let $x \in D$. Then $f(x) \in f(D)$. ...(how to continue?)

<= Let $D \subset A$, and suppose that $f^{-1}(f(D)) = D$. Then we have to show that $f$ is injective. Suppose that for certain $x,y \in A$, we have that $f(x) = f(y)$, and suppose that $f$ is not injective. Then $x \neq y$. Let $D = \left\{x\right\}$. Then $f(D) = \left\{f(x)\right\}$. Hence we have that $f(x) \in f(D)$. But $f(x) = f(y)$, so also $f(y) \in f(D)$, which is a contradiction. Thus $f$ is an injection.

Can someone correct me on the points where I am wrong. Also I don't really understand this step in the first part of the proof: "This means that there is an $y \in D$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$." How can I say something about $y$ on the basis that $f(x) \in f(D)$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You know that $f(x)=z\in f(D)$. By the definition of $f(D)$ it means that $z$ has a source in $D$ (you called it $y$). That is $y\in D$ and $f(y)=z=f(x)$.

Comment: Ok so we have: let $x \in f^{-1}(f(D))$. This means there is an $y \in f(D)$ such that $f(x) = y$. This $x$ is unique. Hence $x \in D$. Correct?

Comment: I wrote it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for any $f$, $$D\subset f^{-1}(f(D)).$$
You need to show that if $f$ is injective then also $$f^{-1}(f(D)) \subset D.$$
Let $x\in f^{-1}(f(D))$ then there exist a $y\in f(D)$ such that $f(x)=y$, by the injectivity this $x$ is unique. Since $y\in f(D)$ it follows that $x\in D$. Thats complete the proof.

Comment: Ok. And it's impossible that $x \in A$ but not in $D$ (after all, $D$ is only a subset of $A$), because we let $x \in f^{-1}(f(D))$, right?

Comment: No. This is because the injectivity. If $f$ was not injective then $x$ could be in $A\setminus D$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you help me out with the second part of the proof (<=) or is that one correct?

Comment: The idea is OK. I think you need to try to write it better.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\in D\implies f(x)\in f(D)\implies x\in f^{-1}\left(f(D)\right)$$

This is the easy direction and it is always true. What you did is *the hard* direction.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But we don't know what $f^{-1}$ is, it doesn't have to be the inverse function. Does that matter or not?

Comment: Its not inverse function. This is just by the definition of $f^{-1}$ as inverse image.

Comment: @Kamil Of course it doesn't have to be the inverse function. This is one of the most striking and annoying cases of double notation in mathematics which can be pretty confusing: $\;f^{-1}\;$ in this case is just the inverse image of.